# Is it possible to have input type="image" without src attribute?

Tags: html, input, src

maybe a little odd, but I'm stuck nevertheless:

I have an input type="image" which acts as a button within a software. I have to tweak the button for a template.

```
<input class="tweaked" src="" title="add to basket" alt="add to basket" type="image">
```

The problem:

- I cannot change the type, because the software seems to "bind" to input type="image"
- If I just omit the src attribute I get failed to load on IE and other browser

Question:

Is it possible to have an input type="image" without src attribute looking nice across browsers, that is without the "failed to load image"-icon? If so, how can it be done?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you able to use JavaScript to change the type once the document has loaded?

Comment: Just a little off topic: You could use a 1x1px transparent gif as a background.

Comment: No, because then I cannot use the input any more, because the functionality is gone. I can switch to input type=button inside the software, but then the button is dead

Comment: @w3d - You can't change the type attribute of an `input` with JS in IE.

Comment: @Teneff: I tried, but that leaves the src="?" element empty. I also tried the 1x1.png as src, but that shrinks the button to 1x1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make the source of the image be a 1x1 clear pixel PNG. It's quick and dirty, and it will most likely work. You may even already have such a file that the site is downloading.

If, however, you don't want to add another HTTP request, perhaps you can set the source to be your image sprite, then in your CSS align the background so that the sprite is way, way off the image. This will get rid of the 1x1clear.png file, but it may degrade in a weird way in some cases.

Comment: just tried that. I have to see if I can CSS the button to it's old format.

Comment: not perfect but I need to set the element width and height via CSS and then make a transparent .png with the alt-text. Waste a http-request...

Answer (score 0):

Wacky idea that probably won't work, but you can try using a css (or jquery) selector to look for a missing src tag and set it to css `display: none` or add a temp src tag pointing to a dummy image.